# How do you address data returned to a socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets, irc

Say you are telneting into IRC to figure out how it all works.  As you issue commands the IRC server returns data telling you what it's doing.  Once I have created a default script that basically is how a normal IRC connection between server and client occurs, if it ever deviates from that it won't tell me what is wrong.  I need to be able to throw exceptions based on what the server returns to me.  How do I do that in python?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question — is it how to throw exceptions in Python, or is it how to write a complete IRC client?

Comment: Neither, actually, although more of the "how to write a complete IRC Client." Obviously, this is beyond the scope of Stack Over Flow.  Basically when I issue a command to an IRC Server such as /nick newnick it typically returns something.  How do I catch that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial which pretty much walks you through an IRC client using sockets in Python:

- [Python and IRC](http://www.devshed.com/index2.php?option=content&task=view&id=607&pop=1&hide_ads=1&page=0&hide_js=1)

Comment: I've already looked at that and I'll revisit this evening.  I'm trying to understand how to view the chat in an object oriented way.  

Thanks!

Comment: I see.  Some other articles by that author (http://www.devshed.com/cp/bio/Peyton-McCullough/) go over using the Python-IRC library, which is an OO wrapper around IRC functionality (based on a quick read).  Maybe looking at how they do it will help.

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is an event-driven networking engine written in Python, and includes support for `IRC` protocols. To access `IRC` functionality, import it:

```
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
```

See an [example here](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/words/documentation/examples/index.html):  ircLogBot.py - connects to an IRC server and logs all messages. The example `__doc__`:

```
"""An example IRC log bot - logs a channel's events to a file.

If someone says the bot's name in the channel followed by a ':',
e.g.

  <foo> logbot: hello!

    the bot will reply:

  <logbot> foo: I am a log bot

Run this script with two arguments, the channel name the bot should
connect to, and file to log to, e.g.:

  $ python ircLogBot.py test test.log

will log channel #test to the file 'test.log'.
"""
```